# How to open text file and change text per paragraph?

Tags: c#

I want to read a text file, and then add text before and after the existing text for every paragraph(text row). The text before and after changes after every paragraph, but repeats after every third one. The original text is always unique for every text row.

Ex: "1text"  -> "Some text 1text Some text". "2text" ->"Some other text 2text Some other text
". "3text" -> " no idea 3text no idea ". "4text" -> " Some text
 4text Some text"

Then replace the textfile with the new one, or create a new one.

Is this something I can build from?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] lines = { "First line", "Second line", "Third line" };

    System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Desktop\TestFolder\WriteLines.txt", lines);

    using (System.IO.StreamWriter file =
    new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Desktop\TestFolder\WriteLines.txt"))
    {
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            if (!line.Contains("Second"))
            {
                file.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't relate to the problem you are solving. What have you tried? You are able to desribe what you want to achieve, you apparently know how to, at least basically, work with text files, so what specific problem did you encounter?

Comment: I dont know much about c# but I want to create a code where I can read a textfile which will be sorted like this:
*www.example.jpg
*www.example.com
*Nice shoes
*
*www.anotherexample.jpg
*www.anotherexample.com
*Cool T-shirt

Infort and after this text I want to add my html code, as they share the same css. Star indicates new row in the text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be something you want, as I understood your intensions correctly:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string readLine;
        string[] lines = { "First line", "Second line", "Third line" };
        int linecounter = 0;
        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\Temp\inputtest.txt");
        System.IO.StreamWriter outputfile = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Desktop\TestFolder\WriteLines.txt");
        while ((readLine = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {    
                outputfile.WriteLine(lines[linecounter] + readLine + lines[linecounter]);
                linecounter++;
                if (linecounter == 3)
                {
                    linecounter = 0;
                }
        }
        file.Close();
        outputfile.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Cheers, this is very much what I needed. The only trouble I have is that it only prints "Second line" and nothing from the previous text file.

Comment: I have updated and tested the code piece, It is working for me. I hope this one is more clean and easier to understand.

Comment: It works like a charm! You made me understad how to use WriteLine and StreamReader/writer properly. Thanks, and I hope you have a superb day!